# Recovery of Old Ecryptfs Data Does not Work

Tags: 18.04, ecryptfs

In order to move to a new SSD, I've installed a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 and am trying to move my old home directory step by step from the old home-partition to a new home partition, both encrypted by ecryptfs.

If I run `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /media/reichelt/Daten/.ecryptfs/reichelt/`, this did not work for the first time anytime I tried. The output is always like:

```
INFO: Found [/media/reichelt/Daten/.ecryptfs/reichelt/.Private/].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: 
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] 
INFO: Enter your LOGIN passphrase...
Passphrase: 
Inserted auth tok with sig [f6d7ded7517731f2] into the user session keyring
mount: /tmp/ecryptfs.1yhDVU8j: mount(2) Systemaufruf ist fehlgeschlagen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden.
ERROR: Failed to mount private data at [/tmp/ecryptfs.1yhDVU8j].
```

So basically the file, where it is mounting, seems to be missing ("Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden.") I can repeat this, and the error persists.

One workaround I found is, that if I run it on a wrong folder, e.g. `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /media/reichelt/Daten/.ecryptfs/reichelt/`, this also fails, but the next time I run `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /media/reichelt/Daten/.ecryptfs/reichelt/.Private/`, it works and I can access files just normally.

The file system of the old partition is definitely ok, I can boot into the old Ubuntu and files open just as usual, and after recovery mounted the old partition correct, everything is just fine.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have the same error when just running `ecryptfs-mount-private`, which never succeeded. The workaround to run `keyctl link @u @s` from this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/1718658/comments/26) helped, maybe it helps you, too?